# Can someone please explain how this sql query is working. The order by portion

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

**Question - -- Return for each customer the customer ID and region
-- sort the rows in the output by region
-- having NULLs sort last (after non-NULL values)

```
select custid
     , region
  from sales.Customers
 order 
    by case when region is null then 1 else 0 end
     , region
```

Comment: `case when region is null then 1 else 0 end` yields `1` when `region` is `NULL` and `0` otherwise. And since `1` > `0` that will order null after non-null values. If that is what you didn't understand. Otherwise you need to be more precise on what you actually don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

Change the query to this:

```
select custid
     , region
     , case when region is null then 1 else 0 end sorter
  from sales.Customers
```

Now can you see what it's doing?